# Why do we need ether in private quorum chain for transactions?

Tags: private-blockchain, quorum

I have created a private quorum chain network. If there is a balance in the account address only then transactions are happening. Why do we need ether balance in quorum private chain or is there something I need to give additionally to do transactions with out ether balance because I have read that quorum private chain doesn't require ether for transactions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need Ether in the account. But Ether is not deducted from the account. Check this issue [issue38](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/38)